# Change scale set virtual network default address 10.0.0.0/16

Tags: networking, ip, address, azure-networking

By default, when creating a scale set through the Azure Portal, that scale set has a a virtual Network with the default address 10.0.0.0/16, even if you are already using that Network for other instances.

1) Does anyone knows how i can change that network range for example into 192.168.0.0/16 and make sure that my instances that now have an ip address from the range 10.0.0.0/21 will receive an IP address from 192.168.0.0/16. I tried to delete the 10.0.0.0 subnet and the Network with the instances deallocated but i was not allowed (failed message)

2) Or is it possible to create a new scale set through the portal and choose what virtual network address range he wants?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone knows how i can change that network range

We **can't** modify virtual network addressPrefix after it created.

> Or is it possible to create a new scale set through the portal and
>   choose what virtual network address range he wants?

We can use Azure VMSS template to deploy VMSS, in this way, we can **modify** the **addressPrefix** and **subnetprefix** before we create VMSS.

First we can use google to search a VMSS template, for example:
[image]

And select **Edit**:
[image]

[image]

Then we use the template to deploy VMSS, here is my result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Jason i will do that in json. But is strange that the Portal doesnt give you the option to also choose your network range, during the selection of your scale set components. I think that i have to return back to powershell and json..

Comment: @Nick I guess you deploy the VMSS with azure marketplace, we can't edit that template. we can find vmss template in github, then deploy to azure.https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates

Comment: @Nick If it helps, please mark it as an answer, it will help others :)